# Delphi 6 doesn't trigger breakpoints

Tags: delphi, settings, development-environment, breakpoints

After installation of Delphi 6 at new working station I issued problem with breakpoints. In debug mode environment doesn't trigger breakpoints like they are not placed at all...

Have you experienced similar situation? I suppose reason is some setting, but I cannot find which one...

TnX in advance!

Nemanja

Comment: Do you have "Debug information" enabled in the project?

Comment: @David Yes, it is checked under Project Options>Compiler.

Comment: Do I need to enable Use Debug DCUs (also under Project Options>Compiler>Debugging)? It is enabled right now.

Comment: What happens if you press F7 to start debugging (rather than F9). This should break at the `begin` line in your .dpr file.

Comment: You only want Use Debug DCUs if you want to step through and break in RTL/VCL code.

Comment: @David If I press F7 istead of F9 nothing happens... Thank you for explanation for DCUs.

Comment: What project are you running? Can you create a brand new project that does nothing (i.e. just a form) and see if you can debug that.

Comment: @David I created new project that only shows message and put breakpoint at line with ShowMessage (as well as before and after, in every case), but nothing happens. It execute command but don't stops at that line of code... And if try to run project with F7, alos nothing happens... I'm not sure that understood your question about 'which project'? What you meant n that question?

Comment: I noticed now that also doesn't work command Ctrl+F2 to Reset Program during debugging... When I checked Run menu item, all items are disabled except Run, Parameters and Evaluate/Modify!!! Not only in debug mode, it is disabled even in regular mode (without debug)!!!

Comment: @Nemanja does the user on this machine have SeDebugPrivilige?

Comment: @David user is in Administrators group, so I suppose it wouldn't be cause of problem. For people who are not introduced with SeDebugPrivilige, I would recommend: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/14/8080140.aspx

Comment: OK, SeDebugPrivilige can't be it because you can always debug your own processes.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether you've been able to resolve this problem.

Comment: @codeelegance I'm not able to reinstall Delphi 6 in this moment, so I will inform you about results when I finish with reinstallation. Other settings and actions didn't solve problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this sometimes happens (not only in 6).

- Enable all debug information except debug DCU's unless you want to debug the Borland code. (Don't forget to check for compiler switches in the code).
- Disable code optimizer.
- Rebuild all code.
- If you are using DLL's be sure to enable debug code in all projects and set the host application to the right executable.

If that fails.

- Be sure that there are blue dots at the code.
- Be sure you have the right source file. You can check this by adding an error (for example dghasgsgd) and recompile, if the compiler accepts, this is not the right source file.
- Be sure the code is reached (add a SendMessage statement or a message box so you can be sure the statement is reached.).
- Restart the compiler. Or even restart the pc.

If that fails.

- Take a break. Have a lunch or get something to drink.
- Return and show the problem to a coworker. (preferably a programmer too).

Comment: -enabled all settings except DCUs; -Project Options>Compiler>Code Generation Optimization disabled; -Code rebuilt; -Using dll's from other projects, in all projects debugging enabled except DCUs; - blue dots during debugging exists; -right source file, error message shown after entering wrong code; -what you thought when said 'add a send message'? not sure that understood that. - going to have a lunch!!! ;-)

Comment: @Nemanja Vujacic, is it just this project or does it fail for all? If its the later, maybe something went wrong with the installation.

Comment: @Gamecat It fails for all projects, so it's per suure not caused by project settings. Probably something went wrong during Delphi 6 installation process. If I don't find what can be reason, I'll try with Delphi reinstall.

Comment: I had this problem as well, for Delphi 6 and 7, all I could do was a complete reinstall which sorted the issue out. Fortunately I have not had issues with 2009 / 2010 or XE. Good Luck

Comment: And one additional note that I noticed and maybe can be useful in resolving this issue: When I'm in debug mode, sometimes Delphi environment block (freestone shown) and I cannot edit code until I turn off my application (not Delphi). When I shut down application, Delphi continue to work normally. Do you now reason for such weird behaviour?

Comment: @Nemanja The IDE disables editing during debugging sessions if the *Mark buffers read-only on run* option is checked in the debugger options. Unchecking it should allow you to edit files while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I applied all settings that @Gamecat suggested, so you can look at this answer like short addition to previous answer.

I missed only one more to solve my problem. In Tools>Debugger Options I checked Integrated Debugging which alive my breakpoints. When breakpoints started to work, I got error message 'Project *_*.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 4CDEB080 in module 'IDPDX32.DLL'. ' For solving this issue I just unchecked option 'Stop on Delphi Exceptions' in menu Tools>Debugger Options>Language Exceptions.

Now Delphi works fine and don't need to reinstall it.

Reason for loosing my previous configuration that worked fine might be in copying my files from one folder to another (as well as config and other temp files) when paths became wrong and after that I probably deleted old config files and started with settings from beginning...

**+1 Tip**: If you get this message: *[Error] RLINK32: Unsupported 16bit resource in file ....\estands\estandar_StdFormMainFrm.DFM* problem is in Text-DFM option. When you right-click on the form in the IDE, is the menu item "Text-DFM" (or maybe called "Text as DFM") checked? If not, do so, save and try to compile.

If somebody knows reason for this behaviour, detailed explanation would be useful. Until now I found this option is for backwards-compatibility to older Delphi-versions.

Comment: Hmm, that would definitely be the problem. The state of the *Integrated Debugging* option is stored in the registry in later versions of Delphi. Its been a while since I've worked with Delphi 6 but I think this setting was stored in a configuration file in the install folder. With it turned off you can set break points all day long and it will never stop on any of them. Glad to see you figured it out.